# Remove duplicates inside a for loop in PHP

Tags: php

I have used for to get some data from a string, now I need to remove the duplicates from it.

The code I have is this:

```
for ($i = 0, $l = count($videos); $i < $l; $i++) {
    $video = explode('>>',$videos[$i]);
    $audio = str_replace(' ','',$video[2]);
    $subs = str_replace(' ','',$video[3]);
    $lang = $audio.'_'.$subs.', ';
}
```

Which returns this:

```
es_en, en_es, es_en, es_en, en_es, en_en,
```

Is there a way to remove the duplicates of it using PHP?

Comment: Put them into an array and use array_unique on it

Comment: `array_unique(explod("es_en, en_es, es_en, es_en, en_es, en_en,",", "))`

Comment: Can I do that inside the for? or is there anything else I must do?

Comment: That returns: `Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , ) Array ( [0] => , )` using it like this: `$arrx = $audio.'_'.$subs.', ';
 $arrx = array_unique(explode($arrx,", "));
 print_r ($arrx);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry I was a bit careless

```
$cache = [];
for ($i = 0, $l = count($videos); $i < $l; $i++) {
    $video = explode('>>',$videos[$i]);
    $audio = str_replace(' ','',$video[2]);
    $subs = str_replace(' ','',$video[3]);
    $lang = $audio.'_'.$subs;
    if (!in_array($lang, $cache)){
        $cache[] = $lang;
    }
}
$result = implode(',', $cache);
```